# Url for http GET request is being cut off when url params sent in url for Http.get

Tags: angular, typescript, get, angular-http

I was having an issue where my url was being cut off. I was manually putting my url together, like

`this.http.get(apiUrl + 'endpoint?filter=' + encodeUri(JSON.stringify(params))`.

This was not working, so I changed it to work like

`this.http.get(apiUrl + 'endpoint', {params:filter})`.

Output from first method: 
http://mydomain/api/endpoint?filter=%7B%22where%22:%7B%22and%22:%5B%7B%22project_id%22:%220232%22%7D,%7B%22floor%22:%22Building%20

Output from second method:
http://mydomain/api/endpoint?filter=%7B%22where%22:%7B%22and%22:%5B%7B%22project_id%22:%220232%22%7D,%7B%22floor%22:%22Building%20#1%7CFloor%20#1%22%7D%5D%7D%7D

As we can see, the first method is missing many characters.
The second method output is the expected output of the first method as well, just not the actual. Can anyone explain why this would be?

Comment: `encodeUri` is meant to be used for the entire URI. You should use `encodeUriComponent`.

Comment: Nice, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EncodeURIComponent` will encode the `#`, encodeURI will not (and is meant for take the entire url and skip the first part before encoding). Passing it with the # will terminate it early.